# What is the Javascript rule for passing extra variables into a method or property

Tags: javascript

My question is about the style transform property, but I also want to ask the same question about any built in Javascript property or method and even user created ones.

For example, the syntax for the style property is listed as follows on w3schools `object.style.transform = "none|transform-functions|initial|inherit"` which suggests that with the transform property you can only add in the values listed e.g transform-functions. 
However with any property or method, in Javascript you seem to able to add in any number of variables not included in the official syntax rule of how that particular property should be syntaxed.

For example, in the case of script below, the line commented `//this line`, the `currentAngle` variable is included in the line of code, however in the syntax description for the transform property there is no mention that you can included variables in the syntax.

I am simply trying to find out what the rule in Javascript is for all this, obviously you can add in variables (and other things?) as the code works, but what is that procedure called in Javascript? I appreciate this is a lengthy question, but it's hard to articulate succinctly.

```js
var currentAngle = 0;
var currentDirection = 0; // 0 - Increasing, 1 - Decreasing

function spin() {
  document.getElementById("myDIV");
  setInterval(function() {
    if (currentDirection == 0) {
      // Allow one complete rotation.
      if (currentAngle < 360) {
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.1," + currentAngle + "deg)"; //this line
        currentAngle += 10;
      } else {
        // Change the direction.
        currentDirection = 1;
        currentAngle -= 10;
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.1," + currentAngle + "deg)";
      }
    } else {
      // Allow one complete rotation.
      if (currentAngle > 0) {
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.1," + currentAngle + "deg)";
        currentAngle -= 10;
      } else {
        // Change the direction.
        currentDirection = 0;
        currentAngle += 10;
        myDIV.style.transform = "rotate3d(0,1,0.1," + currentAngle + "deg)";
      }
    }
  }, 80);
}
spin();
```

Comment: I'm not sure the two things you're talking about are at all related ... one is CSS, the other is arguments to javascript functions?

Comment: Hi Emma, lengthy questions benefit from newlines/paragraphs. Please see how much easier it is to read now I also formatted the code

Comment: Thankyou mplungjan

Comment: `none|transform-functions|initial|inherit` .. so, it can literally be none, initial or inherit ... but "transform-functions" represent a raft of choices

Comment: Jaromanda, so we are closing the gap here, "what raft of choices can "transform-functions" give us? Is this the procedure I am referring to where you can put in any variable etc? What is it called?! :)

Comment: variables are irrelevant - the only thing you can put here is a string ... how that string is constructed is up to you (yes, you can use variables to build a string) - here is the [documentation for CSS transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) - you can see the transform-list can be many transform-function

Comment: Right, so you can put in a string, which could obviously be a great big lot of other code, do you know the javascript rule for this so I can study it further please?

Comment: The transform style property in the code is html dom.

Comment: `which could obviously be a great big lot of other code` - no, it's a string ... the code creates the string, but it's still astring

Comment: `The transform style property in the code is html dom` and? you are dealing with the inline *style* of an element, which is still part of CSS

Comment: OK - fair enough about the CSS and inline style, but what if my original question didn't refer to anything css related, say the property example was a non CSS one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well javascript in itself is just a programming language, and a javascript `Object` is just a structure that can be used to store data in anyway you want it. So you can absolutely write anything you want in any property of any `Object` you'd like.
The catch comes when you try to run the code in a browser. The `style` property of any object allows you to apply css styles to this object. But css is a verify codified and descriptive language, and so if it receives an unknown value or an unknown property, your browser won't be able to interpret it, resulting in an error.

Comment: actually, it wont result in an error - it will result in the style being ignored (sure, an error is logged in the console, but the javascript code wont throw an error)

Comment: "So you can absolutely write anything you want in any property of any Object you'd like." This is very close to answering my question (about to tick answered) ha but need abit more detail what is the procedure in quotes called, are there any rules about said procedure I should know!? Can anyone point me to a page which describes this in more detail :)

Comment: True, my bad here

Comment: @Emma45 What do you mean by procedure ? I think maybe the name you are looking for is Object affectation or Property affectation. You should look at this: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_object_properties.asp

Comment: Oh wait I think I just understood what you mean ! Is it the fact that there are no literal quotes around the variable name that bothers you ?